# Rails create object with param - without require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call a controller function with ajax that works fine, problem is the object generation.

I try it this way:

```
 @tag = Tag.new params[:tagname]
 @tag.save
```

But so I got error 500 back

If I do this

```
@tag = Tag.new params.permit[:tagname]
@tag.save
```

That "works" but in database the column tagname is Null ...

whats the problem?

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing here correctly, your problem is that you're passing a string to `Tag#new`.  However, unless you've modified the Tag class, you actually need to do something like:

`Tag.new name => params[:tagname]`

That is, "new" doesn't take a string (again, unless you've modified it) it takes a Hash.

Comment: Thanks for the hash hint ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a single statement using `create`

`Tag.create(tagname: params[:tagname])`

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution is

```
@tag = Tag.new
@tag.tagname = params[:tagname]
```

Thaks for the hint with hash problem ;)